# Return values from a Python Entrez dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, xml, r, dictionary, ncbi

I want to scrape the Interactions table from the Entrez Gene page.

The Interactions table is populated from a web server and when I tried to use the XML package in R, I could get the Entrez gene page, but the Interactions table body was empty (it had not been populated by the web server).

Dealing with the web server issue in R may be solvable (and I'd love to see how), but it seemed Biopython was an easier path.

I put together the following, which gives me what I want for an example gene:

```
# Pull the Entrez gene page for MAP1B using Biopython

from Bio import Entrez
Entrez.email = "jamayfie@vasci.umass.edu"
handle = Entrez.efetch(db="gene", id="4131", retmode="xml")
record = Entrez.read(handle)
handle.close()

PPI_Entrez = []
PPI_Sym = []

# Find the Dictionary that contains the Interaction table
    for x in range(1, len(record[0]["Entrezgene_comments"])):
   if ('Gene-commentary_heading', 'Interactions') in record[0]["Entrezgene_comments"][x].items():
       for y in range(0, len(record[0]["Entrezgene_comments"][x]['Gene-commentary_comment'])):
          EntrezID = record[0]["Entrezgene_comments"][x]['Gene-commentary_comment'][y]['Gene-commentary_comment'][1]['Gene-commentary_source'][0]['Other-source_src']['Dbtag']['Dbtag_tag']['Object-id']['Object-id_id']
          PPI_Entrez.append(EntrezID)
          Sym = record[0]["Entrezgene_comments"][x]['Gene-commentary_comment'][y]['Gene-commentary_comment'][1]['Gene-commentary_source'][0]['Other-source_anchor']
          PPI_Sym.append(Sym)

# Return the desired values: I want the Entrez ID and Gene symbol for each interacting protein
PPI_Entrez  # Returns the EntrezID
PPI_Sym  # Returns the gene symbol
```

This code works, giving me what I want.  But I think its ugly, and am concerned that if the Entrez gene page changes slightly in format it will break the code.  In particular, there must be a better way to extract the desired information than specifying the full path, as I do with:

```
record[0]["Entrezgene_comments"][x]['Gene-commentary_comment'][y]['Gene-commentary_comment'][1]['Gene-commentary_source'][0]['Other-source_anchor']
```

But I cannot figure out how to search through a dictionary of dictionaries without specifying each level I want to descend.  When I try functions like find(), they operate on the next level down, but not all the way to the bottom.

Is there a wildcard symbol, a Python equivalent of "//", or a function I can use to get to ['Object-id_id'] without naming the full path?  Other suggestions for cleaner code are also appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about xpath in Python, but if the code works, then I would not worry removing full paths or if Entrez Gene XML will change.  Since you first tried R, you could get the XML using a system call to Entrez Direct below or a package like rentrez.

```
doc <- xmlParse( system("efetch -db=gene -id=4131 -format xml", intern=TRUE) )
```

Next, get the nodes corresponding to rows in the table at http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/4131#interactions

```
x <- getNodeSet(doc, "//Gene-commentary_heading[.='Interactions']/../Gene-commentary_comment/Gene-commentary" )

length(x)
[1] 64
x[1]
x[50]
```

Try the easy stuff first

```
xmlToDataFrame(x[1:4])

  Gene-commentary_type  Gene-commentary_text Gene-commentary_refs Gene-commentary_source                         Gene-commentary_comment
1                   18   Affinity Capture-MS             24457600   BioGRID110304BioGRID   255BioGRID110304255GeneID8726EEDBioGRID114265
2                   18 Reconstituted Complex             20195357   BioGRID110304BioGRID   255BioGRID110304255GeneID2353FOSBioGRID108636
3                   18 Reconstituted Complex             20195357   BioGRID110304BioGRID 255BioGRID110304255GeneID1936EEF1DBioGRID108256
4                   18   Affinity Capture-MS     2345592220562859   BioGRID110304BioGRID  255BioGRID110304255GeneID6789STK4BioGRID112665
  Gene-commentary_create-date Gene-commentary_update-date
1                  2014461120                201410513330
2                201312810490                201410513330
3                201312810490                201410513330
4                 20137710360                201410513330
```

Some tags like text, refs, source, and dates should be easy to parse

```
sapply(x, function(x) paste( xpathSApply(x, ".//PubMedId", xmlValue), collapse=", "))
```

I'm not sure about the comments or how Products, Interactants and Other Genes listed in the table are stored in the XML, but I get one or three symbols and three ids for each node here.

```
sapply(x, function(x) paste( xpathSApply(x, ".//Gene-commentary_comment//Other-source_anchor", xmlValue), collapse=" + "))
sapply(x, function(x) paste( xpathSApply(x, ".//Gene-commentary_comment//Object-id_id", xmlValue), collapse=" + "))
```

Finally, since I think Entrez Gene just copies IntAct and BioGrid, you could try those sites too.  Biogrid has a really simple Rest service, but you have to register for a key.

```
url <- "http://webservice.thebiogrid.org/interactions?geneList=MAP1B&taxId=9606&includeHeader=TRUE&accesskey=[ your ACCESSKEY ]"

biogrid <- read.delim(url)
 dim(biogrid)
[1] 58 24

head(biogrid[, c(8:9,12)])
  Official.Symbol.Interactor.A Official.Symbol.Interactor.B      Experimental.System
1                       ANP32A                        MAP1B               Two-hybrid
2                        MAP1B                       ANP32A               Two-hybrid
3                       RASSF1                        MAP1B Affinity Capture-Western
4                       RASSF1                        MAP1B               Two-hybrid
5                       ANP32A                        MAP1B Affinity Capture-Western
6                          GAN                        MAP1B Affinity Capture-Western
```

Comment: Thank you Chris S!  I had planned to write the script in Python, then make a system call to it from R.  But this is much easier (for me, at least).  I was not aware of Entrez Direct, but it nicely solves the web server issue and lets me get back to parsing by Node instead of trying to drill into Python Dictionaries.

Comment: I considered BioGrid, HERD, etc before starting this project, but I like that NCBI collates IntAct and BioGrid into one table and I wanted to start there, if possible.

Comment: I can get just the EntrezID for interacting proteins by specifying: sapply(x, function(x) paste( xpathSApply(x, ".//Gene-commentary_comment//..//Dbtag_db[.='GeneID']//..//Object-id_id", xmlValue), collapse=""))

Comment: Entrez Direct or the rentrez package is useful if you need to save the history (esearch -> efetch).  If you have ids, you could also use `doc <- xmlParse("http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=gene&id=4131&retmode=xml)`

Comment: I forgot the ending quote in the code and can no longer edit the comment.  `doc <- xmlParse("http://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=gene&id=4131&retmode=xml")`.  You can also pass a comma-separated list of ids too.